# How to Encrypt password by using Public Key (.pem) file in php

Tags: php, rsa

I have a Public Key(.pem) file and password to encrypt to use.

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA1aMZtnww+noqWmOfobCE
ivRr5Iih9im26pyk1P2M/ofqke+4ddPDtD4HcfhOuDc0q6KNmuTHwFf+uIjYyIzk
SMnTc+P2jkYfw1zydexTX3b2fKyF6a6y3irJhtKx+PN5y/LOmfTch+A0ycfpCb4E
XvG8hlfWpMpSIJXq/ToPKY+AxFHbIfpRAhOQognLQiogSNe1gZgtDwOVyNjg+c/p
2p8e3SAOpOOr7NRA6Yw4AXn5W4/0mwAlFr5+tDlQqGSyi9VzEuGU1K+0tdj37bnc
/iXe59TH+9uMnZ0utrDmRzMLWBhJiqRYSskqScPlE3nc0tNblXI/n2pSysjt2YDl
eQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

But I am getting value [] for encrypted password. It doesn't get any error but return byte[] values is seem to wrong.

I have code below if it wrong plz help me..

```
<?php
$key = 'MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA1aMZtnww+noqWmOfobCE
SMnTc+P2jkYfw1zydexTX3b2fKyF6a6y3irJhtKx+PN5y/LOmfTch+A0ycfpCb4E
XvG8hlfWpMpSIJXq/ToPKY+AxFHbIfpRAhOQognLQiogSNe1gZgtDwOVyNjg+c/p
2p8e3SAOpOOr7NRA6Yw4AXn5W4/0mwAlFr5+tDlQqGSyi9VzEuGU1K+0tdj37bnc
eQIDAQAB';

include('Crypt/RSA.php');
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

$rsa->loadKey(array(
'e' => new Math_BigInteger(65537),
'n' => new Math_BigInteger(substr($key, 0, -4), -256)
));
$ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt('password(testing8)');

echo bin2hex($ciphertext);
```

Comment: Why would you want to use a public key, you should have no need to decrypt the password? You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79668/login-with-password-hash) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Don't encrypt passwords. Use hashes.